# Replacing only the Text of a link with Image link - Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to replace a text link with an image and still be able to click the image and be directed to the link in the 'a' tag.

The original HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="col-md-1 hidden_grid">

   <ul>
    <li>
     <span class="wlt_shortcode_favs">
      <a onclick="WLTAddF('revistamovil.com.mx', 'favorite', 19, 'core_ajax_callback');" href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_favorites_add ">
       <span>Add Favorites</span>
      </a>
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="detbtn" href="http://revistamovil.com.mx/directorio/example-listing-9/">More Info</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </div>
```

The Jquery I am using does replace the Text with the image but it also removes the link which I want to retain in the HTML when I click the image. it looks like so:

```
<script>
// To change the favorites text for an image

   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $( ".wlt_shortcode_favs:contains('Add Favorites')" ).html("<span><img src='http://revistamovil.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/favoritos.png'></span>");
  });
</script>
```

Note: this is a wordpress site and so there might be a way to do this more easily with php but I feel more confortable using Jquery.

My guess is that I am not targeting the correct element ('Add Favorites' text) but have not figured out how.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
// To change the favorites text for an image

   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $( ".list_favorites_add" ).html("<span><img src='http://revistamovil.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/favoritos.png'></span>");
  });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d312L0zn/)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to reach, but :contains method selects all element so , this also selects the a tag and replace that also, you be more specific can try following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $( ".wlt_shortcode_favs span:contains('Add Favorites')" ).html("<img src='http://revistamovil.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/favoritos.png'>"); 
});
```